# iOS change scene with code

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uialertview

I need to change to another scene after clicking an alert view button.

Here is my code:

```
(IBAction)confirmar {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmar" 
        message:@"Confirma que desea recibir notificaciones en su teléfono móvil" 
        delegate:self 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" 
        otherButtonTitles:@"Si quiero participar", nil];
    [alertView show];
}

(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:
    (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      if (buttonIndex == 1) {        
          inscrito *cambia = [[inscrito alloc] initWithNibName:@"inscrito" bundle:nil];
          [cambia setTitle:@"inscrito"];
          cambia.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
          // [self.navigationController pushViewController:cambia animated:YES];
          [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:cambia animated:YES]; 
          [cambia release];
          NSLog(@"Boton 1");
      }
}
```

I'm trying to change to the UIViewController called "inscrito".

I also added: `#import "inscrito.h"` at top of the file...

Comment: Does NSLog(@"Boton 1"); run?  Is it that nothing happens after the confirm button is pressed or does the app crash?

Comment: yeah, i got the "Boton 1" in the log, but the scene doesnt change.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use UIViewController, but it appears you might want to push the new viewcontroller

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Pushing and Popping Stack Items
– pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animated:

Comment: thanks but unfortunately, for me, i could not understand what I have to do, i read the whole document...

Answer (score 0):

I think the first code is right, but you need to change this :

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:cambia animated:YES];
```

with this :

```
[self presentModalViewController:cambia animated:YES];
```

If you don't have navigationController, it won't work.Hope it help

Comment: Hey Alex, ive removed the ".navigationController", but when i press the button, the aplication get frozen, the button keeps pressed.

The xcode debug says: 2011-11-02 01:06:37.564 taxiAmigo[284:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/xxx/taxiAmigo.app> (loaded)' with name 'inscrito''

Comment: Do you write your NIB name correctly?? You must have "inscrito.xib" in your project. I've use that code and build successfull without error

Comment: Hey! no, here are no "inscrito.xib" in my project. Im using storyboards. Im only have a MainStoryboard.storyboard, my inscrito scene has a view controller called inscrito (with title and indentifier "inscrito"). Should i create a new file in my project called "inscrito.xib" with the data of the controller? Thanks again Alex :)

Comment: Because you are using initWithNibName:inscrito. That means that you call XIB file which name is "inscrito". Try to search code that usually used in IOS 5.